# Combine information in multiple columns into one column on different sheet

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I take data that populates in to different columns on one sheet and transfer them to another sheet, but in the same column? I have tried to run my code, however I am getting an error that says, "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.dewarData" (regarding the last line of code). I have provided a portion of my code below:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data')
const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Overview');
let [vb] = sheet1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,au,az,ba,bb,bc,bd,be])=> 
[`${az} ${ba} ${bb} ${bc}`]);
sheet2.getRange(3,10,vb.length,vb[0].length).setValues(vb);
```

Comment: I have waited for your reply. But, now I noticed your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77229812 From your new question, I understood that my answer and discussion were not useful. In this case, I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Try just `let vb =`