# Join data from different columns into a single column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I take data that populates in different columns on one sheet, and transfer them to another sheet in the same column? I have tried to run my code, however I am getting an error that says, "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.dewarData" (regarding the last line of code). The information that I want are in columns AZ, BA, BB & BC in sheet1 and I want to join them in column J in sheet2. I have provided a portion of my code below:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data')
const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Overview');
let [vb] = sheet1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,au,az,ba,bb,bc,bd,be])=> 
[`${az} ${ba} ${bb} ${bc}`]);
sheet2.getRange(3,10,vb.length,vb[0].length).setValues(vb);
```

Comment: I thought that your this question is the same with your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77226050 How about updating your previous question and removing this question? Or, how about removing your previous question? So, I reopened this question.

Comment: Yes, however my question was not resolved.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Yes, however my question was not resolved.`, I think that the reason for this is due to my poor English skill. I really apologize for this.